# Matplotlib and four contour plots with reflections in the x- and y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, contour, multiple-axes

I have four sets of contour data, and I'd like to plot them on the same graph, in the four quadrants. I'd also like the contours to 'reflect' in the same x- and y-axis, i.e. the center of the plot is the origin for all four plots.

I have the following code::

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2,2, sharex=True, sharey=True)

fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0)

xmin = -1.1
xmax =  2.1
ymin = -1.1
ymax =  2.1

## Top left quadrant
# set_xlim(left, right)
ax1.set_xlim(xmax, xmin)
ax1.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
CS1 = ax1.contour(X_red, Y_red, Z_red, colors='k', levels=levels_red)
ax1.clabel(CS1, inline=1, fontsize=10)

## Top right quadrant
ax2.set_xlim(xmin, xmax)
ax2.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
CS2 = ax2.contour(X_blue, Y_blue, Z_blue, colors='r')
ax2.clabel(CS2, inline=1, fontsize=10)

## Bottom left quadrant
CS3 = ax3.contour(X_Sp, Y_Sp, Z_Sp, colors='b')
ax3.clabel(CS3, inline=1, fontsize=10)
ax3.set_xlim( xmax, xmin)
ax3.set_ylim( ymax, ymin)

## Bottom, right quadrant
ax4.set_xlim( xmin,xmax)
ax4.set_ylim( ymax, ymin)
CS4 = ax4.contour(X_ET, Y_ET, Z_ET, colors='g')
ax4.clabel(CS4, inline=1, fontsize=10)

plt.show()
```

but this is putting the all four contour plots in the top left of their respective quadrantes. Thoughts??!!

Comment: We do not have your data, hence it's hard to reproduce the problem. But surely you do not want to share the axes if you don't want to.. well.. share the axes.

Comment: Got it. Yup, that worked.